# SagePay not receiving all responses from PayPal

Tags: paypal, opayo

I have a client who is using sage pay as their payment provider, it gives the option to pay by paypal when clicking through to sagepay.
It appears for some transactions where the user has selected "Paypal", sagepay is not receiving a confirmation back that the payment was successful. 
Therefore the website is seeing the transaction as failed.
This isn't happening with every paypal transaction but enough that it is starting to cause an issue.

1. Is anyone else having this problem
2. How do I start to think about handling it?

Comment: I've made the assumption that you are using the Server integration method. 

Do you know if the website is responding to the notification post at all in these cases? It could be (and I'm guessing) that the signature value doesn't match and it is rejecting the transaction in some cases....

Comment: Nothing is getting back to Sagepay, it's showing in the Sagepay backend.
Thinking its actually something we need to speak directly the them about?

Comment: That would probably be best. If you have a recent as possible transaction ID (the Sage Pay one), that will help